# populate static values for missing database values

Tags: sql-server-2008, if-statement, join, missing-data

I have a query to pull some records from a database - using a few tables to tie agent names to their sales.  My problem is - the agent phone_id and agent first_name and last_name isn't always in the database.  For those values I'd like to populate "unknown" for their first and last name.  My query as it exists today - just skips them as they don't match.

```
select recordings.ident,users.first_name,users.last_name,recordings.agent_number,recordings.device_id from recordings
  join agent_phones
    on recordings.agent_number=agent_phones.phone_id
      join users
        on agent_phones.agent_id=users.uid
```

is there a way to do some sort of "if" in the query?  so that "if" the agent_number doesn't exist in agent_phones - i can just populate the first_name and last_name with the static "unknown".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `LEFT JOIN` clause, which also includes rows that cannot be joined (don't have matching row in the second/right table). The values from the second/right table are then `NULL`.

```
SELECT recordings.ident, users.first_name, users.last_name, recordings.agent_number, recordings.device_id
FROM recordings
  LEFT JOIN agent_phones
    ON recordings.agent_number = agent_phones.phone_id
  LEFT JOIN users
    ON agent_phones.agent_id = users.uid
```

This can further be extended to return a specified string instead of `NULL` values using the `COALESCE` function:

```
SELECT
    recordings.ident,
    COALESCE(users.first_name, 'unknown'),
    COALESCE(users.last_name, 'unknown'),
    recordings.agent_number,
    recordings.device_id
FROM ...
```

Comment: I would use `'unknown'` not `"unknown"` - in SQL Server `"this is a quoted identifier, not a string"`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you, fixed it.